# Python : How to get index of sub array with most elements in 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been looking for the most efficient method to get the index of a sub array with the most elements within it. For example :

```
array = [[a,b,c],[a,b],[a,b,c,d,e,f]]
```

The answer I should get would be `2`.

How can I get the index of this without using a lengthy for loop process to check each block? Also without the use of Numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]
>>> max(enumerate(l), key=lambda sub: len(sub[1]))[0]
2
```

This will return the lowest index of an element with the maximum number of items (there could be more than one).

Unwrapping what's happening:

```
>>> list(enumerate(l))
[(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 5]), (2, [6, 7, 8, 9, 10])]
```

-> iterable of (index, value) pairs.

```
>>> max(enumerate(l), key=lambda sub: len(sub[1]))
(2, [6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

-> (index, value) pair with the longest value (sublist).

```
>>> max(enumerate(l), key=lambda sub: len(sub[1]))[0]
2
```

-> just the index.

More readable alternative, but with two full passes over the data in the worst case:

```
>>> l.index(max(l, key=len))
2
```

Some low effort timings:

```
In [1]: l = [[0]*i for i in range(10000)]
In [2]: %timeit max(enumerate(l), key=lambda sub: len(sub[1]))[0]
2.05 ms ± 5.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [3]: %timeit l.index(max(l, key=len))
791 µs ± 4.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Looks like the second version is faster even for a list with 10000 elements where the last element is the longest. This is probably due to only calling very efficient builtin functions instead of the custom `lambda`.

Conclusion:

Use **`l.index(max(l, key=len))`**.

(Final edit: the first version could still be faster if you happen to have a list holding objects where calling `index` would trigger some very costly `__eq__` checks.)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly roundabout, but does the job:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> max(enumerate(a), key=lambda (_, el): len(el))
(2, [4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

This gives both the element and its index. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out how to reduce that to just the index.

If you need just the element, things are much simpler:

```
>>> max(a, key=len)
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the systax simple,

```
>>> array = [[a,b,c],[a,b],[a,b,c,d,e,f]]
>>> array.index(max(array, key=len))
2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lamba` to sort the `array` by `len` and then just take the index of the last item

```
x = array.index(sorted(array, key=len)[-1])
# 2
```